# Django Admin not hashing user's password

Tags: django, web, django-admin

I am using `AbstractBaseUser` and `UserCreationForm` with my Django app. When registering users through my app, the password gets saved in hash format and saved in the database. But when I try to do the same thing using Django admin site, the password gets saved in raw format.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to make sure that your model admin class knows how to hash passwords. According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin), if you are using subclassing  `AbstractBaseUser`, then you might be able to extend `UserAdmin`.

Assuming your custom user model is called `CustomUser`, you could try the following.

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ...

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess the problem is that you inherited ModelAdmin instead of UserAdmin from django.contrib.auth.admin in your admin.py.

Sample code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import Employee

class EmployeeAdmin(UserAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Employee, EmployeeAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the custom user model you can introduce a method to check if the password is already hashed. If not hashed,the method should hash the password ie

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   
    if self.password and not self.password.startswith(('pbkdf2_sha256$', 'bcrypt$', 'argon2')):
      
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
    
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```