# Django, can't log in after creating user

Tags: django, authentication, admin

I created user in the Django shell and tried to authenticate it, but can't. That returns `NoneType`. Also, I check that is_superuser, is_stuff, is_active is True

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
>>> User.objects.create(username='user', password='password', email='someemail')
>>> User.objects.all()
>>> <QuerySet [<User: admin>, <User: user>]>
>>> admin
>>> user = authenticate(username='user', password='password')
>>> user
>>> user.is_active
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_active'
>>> type(user)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> admin = authenticate(username='admin', password='wa23sd54fg')
>>> admin
<User: admin>
>>> admin.is_active()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
>>> admin.is_active
True

>>> user = User.objects.get(pk=2)
>>> user
<User: user> 
>>> user.is_active
True
>>> user.is_superuser
True
>>> user.is_staff
True
```

When tried log in with use in admin panel, it shows the error:

> Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have used the [`create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) method, so that the password was hashed correctly:

```
User.objects.create_user(username='user', password='password', email='someemail')
```

If you want the user to be able to access the Django admin, set `is_staff=True` as well:

```
User.objects.create_user(username='user', password='password', email='someemail', is_staff=True)
```

You can fix the password for the existing user in the Django shell with [`set_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password):

```
user = User.objects.get(username='user')
user.set_password('password')
user.is_staff = True  # allow user to log in to Django admin
user.save()
```

Comment: thank you, its help me. But when I create user in admin panel with marked staff, it is steel can't login with. It is not very important, but interesting why it can be happen?

Comment: You haven't shown any code from your admin so we can't tell. Again, it sounds like you aren't hashing the password correctly when you create the user. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851901/django-admin-not-hashing-users-password/32852793#32852793) might help.